# spring boot 1.2.5 @Configuration @Autowired annotation null?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

`PrimaryDatasourceProperties.java` get `application.properties` content, it is right.

`DatasourceConfig.java` inside the method `@Bean ... primaryDataSource ()` no `primaryDatasourceProperties`, `primaryDatasourceProperties` is **null**, which is by @Autowired injected, it is always a problem

May I ask what is the reason?

---

btw:

`DemoApplication.java` try to join`EnableAutoConfiguration`
And
`PrimaryDatasourceProperties.java` try `@Component`

The result is no different

Here is the code:

**resources/application.properties**

```
datasource.primary.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
datasource.primary.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo?characterEncoding=utf8
datasource.primary.username=root
datasource.primary.password=
```

**com.demo.config.PrimaryDatasourceProperties.java**

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.primary")
public class PrimaryDatasourceProperties {
    private String driverClassName;
    private String url;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String getDriverClassName() {
        return driverClassName;
    }

    public void setDriverClassName(String driverClassName) {
        this.driverClassName = driverClassName;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

**com.demo.config.DatasourceConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class DatasourceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private PrimaryDatasourceProperties primaryDatasourceProperties;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
      // primaryDatasourceProperties is null ?
    }
}
```

**com.demo.DemoApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you simply using the default datasource configured by spring boot? Why do you need your own?

Comment: Also you don't really need your own properties object, how to do it is written [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-two-datasources)

Comment: +1 for above. But in case you need that for your own beans  - I think ConfigurationProperties is not automatically Component, so thats why it cant see it while using Autowired.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the annotation `@EnableConfigurationProperties` either to the DemoApplication or your configuration class. See the [manual about that topic](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties).