# spring Cglib is useful but a class @Transactional don't proxy

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions, cglib

Don't know how the transaction doesn't work, I will struggle for a long time, tried a variety of solutions, found that is not being dynamic proxy, so `@Transactional` didn't work

---

And then do a complete copy for `UserService` to `UserService2`

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MbootApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private CacheManager cacheManager;
    @Autowired
    private RoleService roleService;
    @Autowired
    private PermissionService permissionService;
    @Autowired
    private UserService2 userService2;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {

        System.out.println("userService.getClass() = " + userService.getClass());
        System.out.println("roleService.getClass() = " + roleService.getClass());
        System.out.println("permissionService.getClass() = " + permissionService.getClass());
        System.out.println("userService2.getClass() = " + userService2.getClass());

    }

}
```

console.debug

```
userService.getClass() = class cn.cherish.mboot.service.UserService
    roleService.getClass() = class cn.cherish.mboot.service.RoleService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ef060f5f
    permissionService.getClass() = class cn.cherish.mboot.service.PermissionService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d1ee9b4e
    userService2.getClass() = class cn.cherish.mboot.service.UserService2$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$63856500
```

Go against the problem of present in front of the lack of experience a rookie, kneel down! For help

Same code in `UserService` and `UserService2`

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = "users")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class UserService2 extends ABaseService<User, Long> {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;


    @Override
    protected IBaseDAO<User, Long> getEntityDAO() {
        return userDAO;
    }

    @Cacheable(key = "'username_' + #username", unless = "#result==null")
    public User findByUsername(String username) {
        log.debug("username_{}没有缓存", username);
        return userDAO.findByUsername(username);
    }

    public boolean exist(String username) {
        return userDAO.findByUsername(username) != null;
    }

    @Cacheable(key = "'countAllUser'")
    public Long getCount() {
        log.debug("countAllUser没有缓存");
        return userDAO.count();
    }
}
```

Main message with  Bean 'userService' of type [class cn.cherish.mboot.service.UserService] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

```
    2017-02-08 08:47:10.464  INFO 7064 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'userDAO' of type [class org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-02-08 08:47:10.464  INFO 7064 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'userDAO' of type [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy114] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-02-08 08:47:10.465  INFO 7064 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'userService' of type [class cn.cherish.mboot.service.UserService] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-02-08 08:47:10.466  INFO 7064 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'mShiroRealm' of type [class cn.cherish.mboot.extra.shiro.MShiroRealm] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-02-08 08:47:10.486  INFO 7064 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'securityManager' of type [class org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-02-08 08:47:10.487  INFO 7064 --- [           main] c.c.mboot.config.ShiroConfiguration      : ##################从数据库读取权限规则，加载到shiroFilter中##################
2017-02-08 08:47:10.499  INFO 7064 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'filterChainDefinitionMap' of type [class java.util.LinkedHashMap] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-02-08 08:47:10.545  INFO 7064 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor' of type [class org.apache.shiro.spring.security.interceptor.AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-02-08 08:47:10.620  INFO 7064 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7412c5f3] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-02-08 08:47:10.851  INFO 7064 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bd24fc11] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-02-08 08:47:10.897  INFO 7064 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b198c0b5] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-02-08 08:47:10.934  INFO 7064 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'spring.cache-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheProperties' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-02-08 08:47:10.949  INFO 7064 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheManagerCustomizers' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheManagerCustomizers] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-02-08 08:47:10.958  INFO 7064 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.EhCacheCacheConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.EhCacheCacheConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4c378db3] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-02-08 08:47:10.992  INFO 7064 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'ehCacheCacheManager' of type [class net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-02-08 08:47:11.018  INFO 7064 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'cacheManager' of type [class org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-02-08 08:47:11.027  INFO 7064 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'cacheAutoConfigurationValidator' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration$CacheManagerValidator] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
```

My ShiroConfiguration

```
@Slf4j
```

@Configuration
public class ShiroConfiguration {

```
@Bean
public ShiroDialect shiroDialect() {
    return new ShiroDialect();
}

@Bean
public EhCacheManager ehCacheManager() {
    EhCacheManager em = new EhCacheManager();
    em.setCacheManagerConfigFile("classpath:ehcache-shiro.xml");
    return em;
}

@Bean(name = "mShiroRealm")
public MShiroRealm mShiroRealm() {
    MShiroRealm realm = new MShiroRealm();
    realm.setCacheManager(ehCacheManager());
    return realm;
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
    FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    filterRegistration.setFilter(new DelegatingFilterProxy("shiroFilter"));
    filterRegistration.addInitParameter("targetFilterLifecycle", "true");
    filterRegistration.setEnabled(true);
    filterRegistration.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    return filterRegistration;
}

@Bean(name = "shiroFilter")
public ShiroFilterFactoryBean getShiroFilterFactoryBean(/*, permissionDao*/) {

    ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilterFactoryBean = new MShiroFilterFactoryBean();
    shiroFilterFactoryBean.setSecurityManager(defaultWebSecurityManager());
    shiroFilterFactoryBean.setLoginUrl("/login");
    shiroFilterFactoryBean.setSuccessUrl("/admin");
    shiroFilterFactoryBean.setUnauthorizedUrl("/403");

    shiroFilterFactoryBean.setFilterChainDefinitionMap(filterChainDefinitionMap());

    return shiroFilterFactoryBean;
}

@Bean(name = "filterChainDefinitionMap")
public Map<String, String>  filterChainDefinitionMap() {
    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/admin/**", "authc");

    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/user/**", "user");
    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/login", "anon");
    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/logout", "logout");
    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/**", "anon");

    return filterChainDefinitionMap;
}

@Bean(name = "securityManager")
public DefaultWebSecurityManager defaultWebSecurityManager() {
    DefaultWebSecurityManager dwsm = new DefaultWebSecurityManager();
    dwsm.setRealm(mShiroRealm());
    dwsm.setCacheManager(ehCacheManager());
    return dwsm;
}

@Bean(name = "lifecycleBeanPostProcessor")
public LifecycleBeanPostProcessor lifecycleBeanPostProcessor() {
    return new LifecycleBeanPostProcessor();
}

@Bean
public DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator defaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator() {
    DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator daap = new DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator();
    daap.setProxyTargetClass(true);
    return daap;
}

@Bean
public AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor() {
    AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor aasa = new AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor();
    aasa.setSecurityManager(defaultWebSecurityManager());
    return aasa;
}
```

}

and MShiroRealm

```
@Slf4j
public class MShiroRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;


    }
```

Thank you for reading ;)

Comment: [this is a picture for question](http://img.blog.csdn.net/20170207201619134?watermark/2/text/aHR0cDovL2Jsb2cuY3Nkbi5uZXQvY2FpbWVuZ3l1YW4=/font/5a6L5L2T/fontsize/400/fill/I0JBQkFCMA==/dissolve/70/gravity/SouthEast)

Comment: [and the other](http://img.blog.csdn.net/20170207202519012?watermark/2/text/aHR0cDovL2Jsb2cuY3Nkbi5uZXQvY2FpbWVuZ3l1YW4=/font/5a6L5L2T/fontsize/400/fill/I0JBQkFCMA==/dissolve/70/gravity/SouthEast)

Comment: [The root of my problem like this
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31403278/spring-boot-1-2-5-configuration-autowired-annotation-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure `UserService` and `UserService2` have exactly the same annotations on them?

Your `UserService2` class is indeed proxied, so I'd just delete UserService and rename the UserService2 ;)

Comment: I just copy UserService rename to UserService2. So they are same, exactly the same code. Is the code to prove itself without any error.
Whether other spring injection appears to affect UserService?
I am pool in English, sorry!

Comment: Please see my question comment, two pictures.

Comment: Maybe something to do with the `@CacheConfig(cacheNames = "users")`? Maybe they are competing for the same unique `users` name of some sort, resulting in only one of the beans being proxied and the other left as-is? A long shot, I know - just a hunch...

Comment: Originally just a UserService, just to prove its code no problem by copy, 
I found that it is not be proxy, perhaps is a code problem, then a copy to the validation code. And RoleService with similar code structure ....

Comment: If you delete the `UserService2` (and offcourse don't inject it anymore), does the  `UserService` get proxied? In that case, I really believe it has something to do with the duplicate `users` in the cache config annotation..

Comment: [you see this picture](http://img.blog.csdn.net/20170207201619134?watermark/2/text/aHR0cDovL2Jsb2cuY3Nkbi5uZXQvY2FpbWVuZ3l1YW4=/font/5a6L5L2T/fontsize/400/fill/I0JBQkFCMA==/dissolve/70/gravity/SouthEast)
 Under the condition of UserService2 that does not exist

Comment: `
@Slf4j
@Component
public class MShiroRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {

//    @Autowired
//    private UserService userService;
........................
}
`
del ShiroRealm injection , it work,  It must be Shiro configuration problems, thanks

Comment: Is a mixture of configuration and annotations,
The ShiroRealm is @Bean

Comment: When I use Shiro with XML configuration, the UserService can be proxy,
but @Bean configuration for Shiro,  
Bean 'userService' of type [class cn.cherish.mboot.service.UserService] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

Comment: and Bean 'mShiroRealm' of type [class cn.cherish.mboot.extra.shiro.MShiroRealm] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying),  I need your help.

Answer (score 1):

When I change the ShiroConfiguration add this

```
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Bean(name = "mShiroRealm")
public MShiroRealm mShiroRealm() {
    MShiroRealm realm = new MShiroRealm(userService);
    realm.setCacheManager(ehCacheManager());
    return realm;
}
```

and the MShiroRealm changes to Use Constructor to inject UserService

```
private final UserService userService;

@Autowired
public MShiroRealm(UserService userService) {
    super();
    this.userService = userService;
}
```

The UserService can be proxy, Thanks!

```
mShiroRealm.getClass() = class cn.cherish.mboot.extra.shiro.MShiroRealm
userService.getClass() = class cn.cherish.mboot.service.UserService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a3d37fd7
roleService.getClass() = class cn.cherish.mboot.service.RoleService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9b824aa6
permissionService.getClass() = class cn.cherish.mboot.service.PermissionService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7e6ad695
```